# Hook when member updates password

Tags: members, hook, password

I can't seem to find a hook for when a member updates their password.  I am using EE v3.5.4 and just using the built in member templates.  I am sure on existing but I can't seem to find it.  Anyone know what it is?

Answer (score 1):

These what you are after? It appears these are planned for conversion to services down the road.  But should still work now.

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/extension_hooks/global/member_model/index.html#member-update-start

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/extension_hooks/global/member_model/index.html#member-update-end

Comment: Those hooks are fired if the password is updated by the admin in the control panel but they do not seem to be fired when the user updates their own password.

Comment: Just heard from Expression Engine support that there is no hook on the front end when a user updates their own password. :(